# Save response data along with other label using Simple Data Writer

Tags: csv, jmeter

Is it possible to store response data along with other details , reason I need to check for requst which as taken long time from other , I tried other like response writer lister , view tree , but that does not solve the purpose

[image: Here is out put which I am generating]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you will need to switch to XML format:

[image]

It is not possible to save response data in CSV because most probably there will be at least one [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values) character in the response and it will break the CSV structure.

If you don't want XML and still want the response data the easiest option I can think of is going for the [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/)